# I got my passport with letter 214b. Why wasn't I refused at interview?

Tags: usa, visa-refusals

At my interview I was asked several questions

> 1. Why do you want to go to the US

I said I want to go as tourist, I want to take my 6yrs daughter to Disneyland & my son to universal studio.

> 2. Have you traveled before with your family?

I said yes, I had traveled to Singapore & Malaysia with my family

> 3. What do you do for living?

I said I'm a builder. I purchase property & construct them and sell them.

> 4. Do you have any one in the US?

No, I don't know anyone there

> 5. Do you live with your parents?

I said yes, I live with them in the same address.

> 6. How many employees do you have?

I have three employees, one is handling accounts, one is handling sales, one is handling administration.

Then she sees my travel history in my passport & said you are qualified for the visa & kept my passports. Yet I then got my passports back with letter 214b so I'm shocked, why she didn't refuse at the interview?

Comment: Pls help me to know the reason

Comment: The reason for what? Taking your passports and saying you're qualified for a visa? That's very much the opposite of what people usually ask here.

Comment: One assumption would be that a reason to deny you the visa was identified after the interview.

Comment: Henrik I think you had not read the post completely.my concern is that they refused the visa after keeping my passports at the time of interview

Comment: There could have been a clerical error, though it's probably unlikely, and a lot more unlikely that they would admit it. Maybe try to call them to see if that could be the case, telling them you were told you qualified and are thus surprised to have been refused after all. Remember to stay calm and polite even if they are not very helpful.

Comment: @Kawal Kohli Could you have misheard? Perhaps what was said was “you aren’t qualified”? Said quickly, it’s quite easy to hear a positive rather than a negative.

Comment: What did the letter exactly say ?

Comment: How many time you tried to get the US visa? This question is very similar to other ones I saw in this site. Did you can easily afford such travel? (according bank documents). Just having just enough money for travel it is not enough (you are going to Disneyland). Is the father of your kids in US? Probably the rejection was due for other causes. Note: the interviewer will not issue you a visa, she gives just recommendations.

Comment: Traveller thanx for response.but they return your passports if they are not willing & I got my passport from VFS

Comment: @KawalKohli The procedure may have changed for whatever reason. They may have had issues with people becoming belligerent when told they didn't qualify right away, so they may prefer to wait until you're out of the building before they tell you, for instance. Have you tried calling them to check if there was an error?